# How to join exclusively by date range in Hive SQL?

Tags: join, hive, left-join, hiveql, non-equi-join

I have two subqueries that i'd like to join only by the date range between open and closed date from the first table.

First table example:

```
| id_original | open_datetime     | close_datetime    |
|-------------|-------------------|-------------------|
|      1      |2019-01-01 10:00:02|2019-01-02 11:00:21|
|      2      |2019-01-01 10:05:52|2019-01-05 16:45:12|
|      3      |2019-01-03 00:00:43|2019-01-03 23:12:44|
```

Second table example:

```
| category | all other columns...| open_date         |
|----------|---------------------|-------------------|
|    A     |        ...          |2019-01-01 11:00:00|
|    B     |        ...          |2019-01-02 19:10:10|
|    C     |        ...          |2019-01-03 08:23:45|
|    D     |        ...          |2019-01-04 18:10:53|
```

Desired output:

```
| id_original | category | all other columns...| open_date         |
|-------------|----------|---------------------|-------------------|
|      1      |    A     |        ...          |2019-01-01 11:00:00|
|      2      |    A     |        ...          |2019-01-01 11:00:00|
|      2      |    B     |        ...          |2019-01-02 19:10:10|
|      2      |    C     |        ...          |2019-01-03 08:23:45|
|      2      |    D     |        ...          |2019-01-04 18:10:53|
|      3      |    C     |        ...          |2019-01-03 08:23:45|
```

This is my code:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT id, open_datetime, close_datetime
    FROM table1
    WHERE id IN (list_of_ids)
) t1
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT *
    FROM table2
    WHERE other_conditions
) t2 ON t2.open_date >= t1.open_datetime AND t2.open_date <= t1.close_datetime
```

I know that Hive SQL doesn't support inequality as conditions for a `JOIN`. But how should I approach this matter?

Note: The join I need is exclusively for dates, there is no equal key from t1 and t2 that I can use to join them.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Move the join condition to the WHERE clause. In this case LEFT JOIN is transformed to CROSS, because you do not have other join conditions, and join without conditions is CROSS-join. After the cross join, filter rows in the WHERE clause. Though CROSS join may cause serious performance issues if it is not possible to filter rows or join by some other key to avoid CROSS product. If one of the table is small enough to fit into memory, CROSS-join will be executed as map-join, this also will help to improve performance.

```
set hive.auto.convert.join=true;
set hive.mapjoin.smalltable.filesize=512000000; --try to set it bigger and see if map-join works
                                                --setting too big value may cause OOM exception 

SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT id, open_datetime, close_datetime
    FROM table1
    WHERE id IN (list_of_ids)
) t1
CROSS JOIN 
(
    SELECT *
    FROM table2
    WHERE other_conditions
) t2 
WHERE (t2.open_date >= t1.open_datetime AND t2.open_date <= t1.close_datetime)
   OR t2.category is NULL --to allow absence of t2 like in LEFT join
;
```